# AlarmManager With BroadcastReceiver Not Firing

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I have an `AlarmManager` that is set in a `BroadcastReceiver` subclass using a `Service` subclass as the context. The `AlarmManager` is not firing. I know that the `AlarmManager` is being set with the correct milliseconds.

Any ideas for why the AlarmManager is not firing?

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static final String TAG = "Alarm";
        public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        public AlarmManager alarmManager;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Alarm set off onReceive");

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
            wl.acquire();

            //Put to code to execute upon alarm here

            //Check to see if the sounds are playing, if they are stop them.
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                //Call play will simulate the user tapping the play button which will stop the sounds.
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }

            wl.release();
        }

        public void setAlarm(Context context, long milliSeconds, MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            //Set the mediaPlayer member var
            mediaPlayer = mp;

            //Figure out the time to stop the timer in milliseconds
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeToSetAlarmTo = currentTime+milliSeconds;
            Log.d(TAG, "Current Time = " + currentTime + "Time to add = " + milliSeconds + "Time to set timer to = " + timeToSetAlarmTo);

            //Create the intent
            Intent i = new Intent("SmartlifeSoftware.START_ALARM");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

            //Set the alarm
            alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, timeToSetAlarmTo, pendingIntent);

        }

        public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("SmartlifeSoftware.START_ALARM");
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmManager.cancel(sender);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Manifest code under the application tag

```
    <receiver android:name="services.Alarm" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SmartlifeSoftware.START_ALARM">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. In the `alarmManager.set` method, I changed the `int type` paramter from `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`to `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`. `RTC_WAKEUP` specifies an excat time to fire.

From the docs:

`RTC_WAKEUP`—Wakes up the device to fire the pending intent at the specified time.

`ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`-Alarm time in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (time since boot, including sleep), which will wake up the device when it goes off.

Answer (score 0):

Your alarm does not not fire with AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP bacause your triggerAtMilis parametrer is wrong. You should change:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeToSetAlarmTo = currentTime+milliSeconds;
```

to

```
long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
long timeToSetAlarmTo = currentTime+milliSeconds;
```